Regarding update data in SiriKit intent definition file
I am working on Intents of widget , I am getting data from userDefaults and show in SiriKit intent list , data stops updating after some entires , Any help will be appropriate.
I tried with Donation but that doesn't work I need my intent file should be up to date as I update list of themes from app.
provideWidgetTypeOptionsCollection(for intent: SelectThemeIntent) async throws -> INObjectCollection<WidgetType> {
        var arrwidgetType = [WidgetType]()
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group..baseproject")
        guard let arrName = userDefaults?.array(forKey:"arrWidgetName") else {
            let collection = INObjectCollection(items:arrwidgetType)
            return collection
        }
        for i in 0..<arrName.count {
            let widgetType = WidgetType(identifier:arrName[i] as? String, display:"Widget\(i+1)" , subtitle:arrName[i] as? String, image:nil)
            widgetType.name = "Widget\(i)"
            arrwidgetType.append(widgetType)
        }
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items:arr)
        return collection
    }

This is snippet of my code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have updated my question. Please check and help
